# Unlimited history in tmux

Tags: tmux

In your `.tmux.conf` file you can set the window history with something like:

`set -g history-limit 4096`

Is there a way to set an unlimited history for each window?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From what I can tell, you can only do this in a "practical" fashion, by setting the history to an absurdly large number. e.g.:

`set -g history-limit 999999999`

UPDATE: see the other answer as to why you don't want to use a number this high. Something more reasonable (less 9's) would be best.

UPDATE again: perhaps pre-allocation doesn't occur. @Volker Siegel's comment on the other answer indicates that setting the value does not cause memory allocation.

Comment: See warning in the answer of @ThomasAdam.

Comment: See my comment on his answer. :)

Comment: @kenny how do you know its set? is there a way to query the currently active limit on tmux?

Answer (score 56):

Do NOT set it to something like:

```
set -g history-limit 999999999
```

This will pre-allocate that many lines (and hence memory) for all windows, which is going to cripple your machine the more history is stored over time.

Set it to something large, by all means but not THIS large.

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know. I guess you just have to balance the size with comfort that everything you dump will be there.

Comment: Looks like the time is comming where we need to do actual benchmarks :-)

Comment: Ha, I did a comparison, starting tmux with either of the  history-limit values; Memory is the same after start, so tmux does not preallocate the scrollback buffer. (Of course, that does not solve the practical problem)

Comment: I found another interesting investigation into tmux's memory usage at http://blog.42.be/2015/02/tmux-memory-usage-on-linux.html

Comment: To sum up @Silveri's link: tmux had a bug, as it did not release its buffers. Fixed. (as of google group and also merged if I did not misunderstand https://github.com/42wim/tmux/network)

Comment: Why debian doesn't have -g parameter?

Comment: How large is recommended?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to have a reasonably big history and install the [tmux logging plugin](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-logging/blob/master/README.md)

I like to have logging in all tmux windows turned on by default.  I log to a 'tmux_log' directory and have a cron job to delete very old logs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about your memory exploding and only care about a temporary solution (like one noisy pane), you can just set the value in your tmux prompt.
(assuming you have you prefix set to the <Ctrl+B> default)

```
<Ctrl+B>:
```

Then you'll see a prompt at the bottom of the screen where you can type:

```
set history-limit 9999999
```

or whatever limit you want and then press enter.

This lasts for the whole tmux session, in all panes and windows, but won't be persisted in the config and is easily reset in the same way it was set.

Comment: You can also simply run internal `tmux` commands like these on the command line, eg `tmux set history-limit 9999`